# Tailwind - css rule is invisible if I use layer

Tags: tailwind-css

Do you have any ideas why `@layer` in Tailwind CSS doesn't work?

If I write in my styles.css for example

```
h1 {
  @apply text-2xl;
}
```

it works but if I do:

```
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-2xl;
  }
}
```

it doesn't. It just doesn't see this style.

Comment: We need to see the whole CSS file. Do you have `@tailwind base;` before your `@layer` ?

Comment: Yes, I have `@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;` at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I have got same error but i figured out from inspecting elements that inherited styles have been applied then i add some more styles to strong elements then mounted css styles have more precedence because of selectors and it worked..

```
@layer base {
    h1 {    
        @apply text-green-600 font-bold text-4xl;
    }  strong {
        @apply text-gray-800 font-extrabold text-2xl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your `h1` style is getting purged by Tailwind's styler purging process: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size:

> Using the @layer directive will also instruct Tailwind to consider
> those styles for purging when purging the layer.

Since, presumably, you're not referencing the `h1` style with `@apply`, maybe Tailwind is considering the style unused. Although, one would hope that Tailwind would not purge a tag-based selector.

Take a look at the CSS file that is built, either on the file system or inspector in the browser, and look for your `h1` styles.

From the Tailwind docs, maybe try adding `h1` to your whitelist - although I don't think it will work since the whitelist seems to want class-based selectors.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.html'],

    // These options are passed through directly to PurgeCSS
    options: {
      whitelist: ['bg-red-500', 'px-4'],
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

I recommend asking if tag selectors work with layers on the Tailwind Discord or forum: https://tailwindcss.com/community

Comment: I tried and it didn't helped. Also, h1 is just an example but with class selectors it also doesn't work. And tag selectors should work with layers because it's in documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles